# Pass list of folders to zip command

Tags: zip, arguments

I have a folder which contains lot's of folders in it.

I don't need to zip all of them and I have a list of folders that need to be zipped in a separate file

The folder list is in the following format:

```
folder1 folder2 folder3...
```

Can I do something like this (this doesn't work, but I don't know how to pass arguments properly):

```
zip -r backup1.zip < listOfFolders.txt
```

Comment: I'm using windows and am connected via putty on my server and man pages aren't available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the option `-@` to make `zip` read a list of files from its standard input.

```
$ cat listOfFolders.txt | zip -r@ part1.zip
```

Comment: The list of files must be one per line

Answer (score -1):

```
zip backup1.zip -r@ < listOfFolders.txt
```

Option `r@` makes zip read inputs from stdin.

If you don't want to pass list of files from a temporary file **listOfFolders.txt**, We can use grep to filter files and pass results to zip as follows

```
grep -rl "<parent_folder_name>" <file/folder_name_regex> | zip backup1.zip -r@
```

(or)

As mentioned in the above answer like

```
listOfFolders zip -r@ backup1.zip
```